# How could I redirect or deny users from a particular country with my htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ip-address

I looked at [countryipblocks.net](http://countryipblocks.net), and need to clarify...

If I want to block users from, say, Andorra from visiting my site, what exactly needs to be added to my (already existing) .htaccess file?

Do I need to simply add this block of text to my .htaccess?

```
<Limit GET HEAD POST>
order allow,deny
deny from 85.94.160.0/19
deny from 91.187.64.0/19
deny from 194.117.123.178/32
deny from 194.158.64.0/19
deny from 195.112.181.196/32
deny from 195.112.181.247/32
allow from all
</LIMIT>
```

On the other hand, if I want to redirect users from, say, Croatia, from http://mywebsite.com to http://google.com or a landing page, what exactly needs to be added to my .htaccess file?

Finally - how would "deny" appear to the user being denied access?

Thanks.

Comment: What's tiny Andorra done to you for you to want to block it? Its Internet users will be in *tears* when they hear this. I happen to know them both personally and know they'll take this pretty hard.

Comment: That was just an example. :) I've a few countries (2-3) from where users are being a nuisance (spamming etc) that I'd like to avoid access to for now. Andorra is not one of them, thankfully!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visitors who are within a IP range that is banned by `deny` will be served with a 403 error.  If you want to them to see a nice page, instead of the standard Apache error, then you will need something like

`ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403.html`

in your .htaccess file.  It is fairly easy to check rules based on IP addresses are working in your .htaccess by setting the blocked IP to be 127.0.0.1 (*i.e*. localhost); when you then look at the page in question on localhost, you should see the result of the page being blocked.

In answer to your question about redirecting users, blocking **all** users from any 1 country seems a little bit overkill; however, try reading up on the `RewriteCond` directive.

Comment: Ok. I have the code in the original post above inserted into the htaccess file. However, when I tried banning/denying my own IP address, I see that I am not redirected to any 403 page - I am still able to access the site. Any idea why? Is the text above wrong?

Comment: Add this to the top your .htaccess, and try and load any page on localhost; it should return a Forbidden error:

`order allow,deny
deny from 127.0.0.1` (note there should be a line break between the 2 denys).  If you upload this .htaccess file to your host, you should see the website as expected.   Why have you for `<LIMIT GET HEAD, POST>` at the beginning of your code? What purpose does it have?